# Three buttons' width not adding 100% with percentages

Tags: html, css

### Code

```css
.w-33 {
  width: 32%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.w-33.first {
  width: 32%;
  margin-left: 0;
}
button {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  font: 22px sans-serif;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #644eb5;
}
button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="w-33 first">Join League</button>
<button type="button" class="w-33">Start League</button>
<button type="button" class="w-33">Choose Later</button>
```

### What I'm trying to do

I have three buttons that are supposed to fill the width of their parent (of variable width).

The first is supposed to be exactly **32%** of the width, with no margin; the other two are also **32%** of the width but with a **2%** `margin-left` value.

Therefore it should equal 100%:

```
Each button
[  32% + 0%  ] [  32% + 2%  ] [  32% + 2%  ]

Added
[     32%    ] [     34%    ] [     34%    ]

Cumulative
[     32%            66%           100%    ]
```

Why do they overfill when they should be at 100% and how can I make them fit the exact width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue which occurs with inline elements. They will render the white space between the elements.

Try putting `float: left` on the buttons. That will ensure they have no spacing between the buttons.

You could also edit you html so that there is no gap between your buttons

```
<button></button><button></button>
```

[See here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for a good explanation of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Spacing is added between buttons as they are by default inline displayed. Use `float: left` on the buttons.

```css
.w-33 {
  width: 32%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  float: left;
}
.w-33.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}
button {
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  font: 22px sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #644eb5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="w-33 first">Join League</button>
<button type="button" class="w-33">Start League</button>
<button type="button" class="w-33">Choose Later</button>
```